# How to use AES_ENCRYPT mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

I want to use AES_ENCRYPT in my query to insert encrypted data. 
So i have write below query to convert text into encryption

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('1234567#','testingpart') |
```

So i got the below output

```
0x9427909a49cf68afb9494b25363ab14d
```

But i want output like `9427909A49CF68AFB9494B25363AB14D`Remove 0x and convert all character into capital.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [hex function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex)

```
SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('1234567#','testingpart'))
```